# LINQ groupby, divide and extract

Tags: c#, linq

My program is storing same fetched data in a list of tuples

```
public List<Tuple<int, double, double, double, double>> Temp = new List<Tuple<int, double, double, double, double>>();
```

Take this as and example

```
Temp.Add(new Tuple<int, double, double, double, double>(1, 1.1, 0.4, 0, 100.1));
Temp.Add(new Tuple<int, double, double, double, double>(2, 1.1, 0.4, 1.1, 99.1));
Temp.Add(new Tuple<int, double, double, double, double>(2, 1.1, 0.4, 1.3, 55.1));
Temp.Add(new Tuple<int, double, double, double, double>(1, 2.2, 0.4, 0, 100.2));
Temp.Add(new Tuple<int, double, double, double, double>(2, 2.2, 0.4, 1.1, 50.2));
```

I have to summarize the data so that the Tuples that have the same T2 and T3 are returned with their T4 and their T5 divided by the T5 of the first tuple that has that T2 and T3.

If we look at the example, the first 3 tuples have the same T2 and T3, so my end result would be

```
[2, 1.1, 0.4, 1.1, (99.1/100.1)] //<- the 2nd tuple with its T5 divided by the 1st tuple T5
[2, 1.1, 0.4, 1.3, (55.1/100.1)] //<- the 3rdtuple with its T5 divided by the 1st tuple T5
```

Then the 4th and 5th tuples also have the same T2 and T3, so:

```
[2, 2.2, 0.4, 1.1, (50.2/100.2)] //<- the 5th tuple with its T5 divided by the 4th tuple T5
```

I am stuck at:

```
var norm_result = Temp.GroupBy(x => new { x.Item2, x.Item3 })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        AA = x.Key.Item2,
        BB = x.Key.Item3,
        CC = ??, //Item4
        DD = ??, // Item5 divided by its first value in the group
    });
```

Comment: "first tuple that has that T2 and T3" first by what set of sorting rules? When you group items I don't think you will be guaranteed they are in any kind of order.

Comment: @TJRockefeller, ahh, I did not know that. If order is not maintained, the "first tuple" would be the one that has T1 = 1

Comment: For `Enumerable` at least some overloads guarantee the order. From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0): _"The `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>` objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order that the elements that produced them appear in source."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each group in your `GroupBy` statement has a collection of the items in that group, and the `Key` of that group, so when calculating your norm results you need to enumerate through each group to do your calculations.

```cs
var norm_result = Temp.GroupBy(x => new{ x.Item2, x.Item3 })
    //Since this select statement returns IEnumerables for each grouping
    //this will be an IEnumerable of IEnumerables. If you want to flatten
    //things into a single IEnumerable you could do a SelectMany here.
    .Select(x =>
    {
        //sort by Item1, hopefully the order of the items after the first
        //doesn't matter since they all seem to be a value of 2.
        var sorted = x.OrderBy(item => item.Item1).ToList();
        //this is the first item in the group that has Item1 == 1
        var first = sorted[0];
        //skip the first since it appears that you are wanting to skip
        //the first value in your norm results and the select here will
        //return an IEnumerable of the remaining items in the group with
        //the dividing logic
        return sorted.Skip(1).Select(item => new
        {
            item.Item1,
            item.Item2,
            item.Item3,
            item.Item4,
            Item5 = item.Item5 / first.Item5
        });
    });
```

Comment: Indeed, this does it. Just one fix `Item4 = item.Item4 / first.Item5,` should be just `item.Item4`

Comment: @pisistrato I did that based on how you phrased your question "with their T4 and their T5 divided by the T5 of the first tuple" I can update it.

Comment: my apologies for the bad grammar, English is not my first language, with the "and their" I wanted to specify that only T5 should have been divide.